# How to set a specific precompiled header file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to set a non-default precompiled header file in Xcode? For example, instead of Project_Prefix.pch being the precompiled header, could I set it to SomeOtherHeader.h?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select the target, select Build Settings, search for Prefix Header and change the setting

Comment: Note that you'll probably need to change the setting to say something like:  `YourProjectName/FileName.pch or $(SRCROOT)/FileName.pch`

Answer (score 5):

In XCode 6.1 it's under Build Settings > Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language